# limit the no of characters detected in pytesseract

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, captcha, python-tesseract

So I've a captcha image that I'm trying to decode using pytesseract. I've done all the preprocessing using opencv then my current image is -

[image]

Now when I'm using pytesseract it is giving me an output:

```
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config = '--psm 7'))

gTKYWS5
```

Is there a way to limit the no off characters detected as I know all my images would have 6 characters.

Comment: On my computer, I get gTKYW5. Have you tried using a different psm ? Maybe you can find more details here : https://ai-facets.org/tesseract-ocr-best-practices/

Comment: Try using `--psm 6` to tell Pytesseract to treat the image a single block of text